# Intento hacer foto con la webcam y opencv pero se queda en un bucle infinito

Tags: python, opencv

Estoy intentando hacer un programa simple, el cual tome una foto usando el modulo opencv, para acceder a la cámara, y python.
El problema es que, cuando se ejecuta esta línea de código.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

El programa se queda en un bucle infinito y no responde, ya he intentado interrumpir el programa usando ctrl + C, pero no funciona, y la única forma que tengo de detenerlo es cerrando el terminal.

Aquí esta el código completo.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)#Aqui es donde se queda en bucle

readed, frame = cap.read()

if readed == True:
    cv2.imwrite("foto.png", frame)
    print("Foto tomada...")
else:
    print("Error al tomar la foto...")

cap.release()
```

Este es la segunda versión del código que sigue teniendo el mismo error.

```
print("Programa iniciado...")

import cv2

print("Tomando la imagen...")
#Activar la camara
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #Aqui es donde se queda en un bucle infinito

#Avanzamos frame a frame
while(cap.isOpened()):
    readed, frame = cap.read()

    print("Procesando...")
    if readed == True: #Si hay imagenes que no estén corruptas readed = True  
        #Guardamos la imagen
        cv2.imwrite("imagen.png", frame)
        
        #Mostramos la imagen  
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

    else:
        print("Error imprevisto...")
        break

#Cerramos todo
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
print("Programa finalizado...")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de mucho tiempo (y de cambiar de computadora) descubrí que el verdadero problema del codigo era que el modulo "cv2" tuvo un error en la instalación y por lo tanto no se ejecutaba de forma incorrecta.

PD: El codigo [@Lleims](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/56616/lleims) funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 1):

La estructura para llevar ese objetivo a cabo debe estar dentro de un bucle, `while`. A continuación te muestro los pasos:

```
import cv2

# Cargar vídeo
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Trabajamos frame a frame
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # ret será verdadero mientras haya frames a trabajar y no estén corruptos.
    # (Esto es sobretodo útil cuando trabajamos vídeos)
    if ret==True:    
        # Mostramos la imagen por pantalla    
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

        # Si se pulsa una tecla guardamos su valor en 'key'
        key = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if key == 27:
            # Si queremos interrumpir el video y salir apretamos la tecla 'esc'
            # (ascii = 27)
            break
        elif key == 32:
            # Si queremos guardar frame actual apretamos tecla 'espacio' (ascii=32)
            print('Hacemos foto')
            cv2.imwrite('myFolder/img.png', frame)

    else:
        break

# Liberamos el sistema
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

¡Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: Gracias, por corregir mi código, pero aun sigo con el mismo problema.

Comment: Con mi código también? Edita tu pregunta y pon abajo todo tú código para verlo por favor.